# separate the two matches

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Regex problem:
I want to get groups twice, but don't know how to solve it.

Here is code:

```
public static void multiGroupTest() {
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(\\d\\d)(\\w+)");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{1})(\\d+)([A-Za-z]+)");
    String str = "X89SuperJavaJavaX89SuperJava";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
    }
}
```

OK, the result is:

```
X
89
SuperJavaJavaX
```

What i want to get is:

```
X
89
SuperJavaJava
X
89
SuperJava
```

How can I separate the two matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the last group `([A-Za-z]+)` would greedily match the following X , you didn't able to get two strings. Use `((?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+)` to capture the words which are in this `FooBar` format. Because names wouldn't end with a capital letter.

```
([A-Z])(\\d+)((?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qO6mC0/6)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])(\\d+)((?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+)");
String str = "X89SuperJavaJavaX89SuperJava";
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

**Output:**

```
X
89
SuperJavaJava
X
89
SuperJava
```

Comment: It works and solve the problem which i don't realize

Answer (score 3):

Change your `Pattern` to add a negative lookahead for the digit:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{1})(\\d+)([A-Za-z]+)(?!\\d)");
String str = "X89SuperJavaJavaX89SuperJava";
```

**Output**

```
X
89
SuperJavaJava
X
89
SuperJava
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-Z]{1})(\d+)((?:(?!\1)[a-zA-Z])+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/59

Comment: @vks This is the second time I see one of your working answers down-voted with no explanation, +1 to offset unjust down-vote